# If we did have a proven 'Theory of Everything' from physics, would it help to know why there is a universe?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, phenomenology, universe

From a 2022 review by a philosopher, of a 2021 book I haven't read by a physicist, quoting from a 1998 book I haven't read by a physicist:

> What’s Eating the Universe is undoubtedly a very interesting book.
> Davies presents a concise summary of the latest state of research in
> cosmology and elementary particle physics, and shows us the links
> between exact science and many significant philosophical problems.

> Physicists can explain the evolution of the universe as far back as
> the first split second. It’s one of the greatest scientific
> achievements. So far, it has not been possible to combine quantum
> mechanics with general relativity and formulate a “theory of
> everything” (TOE, or quantum gravity). However, in A Brief History of
> Time, Stephen Hawking has written that “if we do discover a complete
> theory, it should in time be understandable in broad principle by
> everyone, not just a few scientists. Then we shall all, philosophers,
> scientists, and just ordinary people be able to take part in the
> discussion of the question of why it is that we and the universe
> exist. If we find the answer to that, it would be the ultimate triumph
> of human reason - for then we would know the mind of God”. Davies
> would probably agree with that view.

P.s. Hawkings said in 2014 “What I meant by ‘we would know the mind of God’ is, we would know everything that God would know, if there were a God, which there isn’t. I’m an atheist.”

P.p.s. Paul Davies had a controversy where he apparently compared scientists belief in immutable laws to religious faith, but seems to have complained he wasn't directly equating them.

P.p.p.s. I didn't intend this question to be about religion or faith Vs science at all. I find it strange that Hawkings was misleading in his popular book (saying God. Also saying 'we and the universe exist' as if separate), and then I think misleading in his later statement in the opposite way (because if we don't know why there's a universe, how do we know  there wasn't a mental creator of it, given that we have evidence that minds which can create things can evolve within a universe).

P.p.p.p.s to qualify as a physical 'theory of everything', should it also explain phenomenal consciousness? (why and where qualia), and might that help know why there's a universe?

Comment: OT: I'm with you on Paul Davies. Any scientist who believes there are immutable laws is like a religious fundamentalist. The so-called laws aren't laws at all: they are a set of observations which evolve over time. Newton wasn't wrong, but incomplete. It's almost as though that kind of scientist has transferred the history of science to themself; and they personally control nature. Earlier, there was a pivotal moment when it was realised that planets orbit the sun, not the earth, and I wonder whether another fundamental shift in understanding is yet to come, that simplifies something.

Comment: We might never discover that there is a determinate causal total "at all," or an ensemble of such cosmoi, or perhaps even weirder things besides. But so "proven," "everything," and "*why* there is a proof of all these things" are demanding tasks to set ourselves; we are minded to be cautious about our ability to achieve them in some ultimate and permanent manner.

Comment: Reading more of the Davies controversy, he seems to be a deist who suspects we're the only life in the universe, plus he can't imagine how we could get qualia out of just atoms (what about some form of panpsychism). I think he wants the existence of the 'laws' themselves to be given more scientific attention because he suspects they've been set specifically here for us to develop.

Comment: A “Theory of Everything” would unify all four forces under a single framework. As such, this question belongs on Physics.SE, since so few here are qualified to even discuss this subject. I’d note: a TOE has nothing to do with qualia. TOEs are an issue for particle physics and cosmology, Quantum Physics and General Relativity.

Comment: [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything) Hawkings later said that a ToE is impossible.

Comment: I followed the citation through and Hawking says "Maybe it is not possible to formulate the theory of the universe in a finite number of statements. This is very reminiscent of Godel's theorem. This says that any finite system of axioms is not sufficient to prove every result in mathematics." But one response says experimental evidence would be sufficient. I note that Hawking there points out that we're not separate from universe, as he earlier implied.

Answer (score 5):

If we had a correct theory of literally everything then yes it would by definition explain the origin of the universe, consciousness, and every other problem. However, the term Theory of Everything has a narrower scope than its literal meaning suggests. Physicists would be happy to claim they had a theory of everything if they could find a single formulation that accounted for quantum mechanics and general relativity, and that wouldn't necessarily shed light on what, if anything, happened before the Big Bang.

On a separate note, I do not know why Stephen Hawking held the view that a TOE should be understandable by everyone. It seems patently obvious that most of theoretical physics is anything but easy to understand, even in general terms.

Comment: He said understandable "in broad principle". The unanswered question is what clues would that give us to why there's a universe.

Comment: @yop thanks, yes I'd spotted that. I think my objection to what he said is that if you make the principles broad enough for everyone to understand, most of what is important to understand gets lost.

Comment: I assumed you had just left it out. What's important could be e.g. spacetime isn't fundamental but emerges from something else, which could have obvious implications for why universe.

Comment: @yop, yes, agreed. There could be all kinds of unexpected findings which might or might not shed light on why the Universe exists. I think the key point from the perspective of your question is that in the world of physics  the success criteria for the declaration of a TOE don't necessarily include the ability to explain why the Universe exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A theory of how will not necessarily explain why. Why not nothing? It would be simpler. Was the transition from nothing to something spontaneous?

Answer (score 0):

By formulating a theory - by definition - you admin that you do not know how something works, because if you knew, you would not need a theory, you would just know. A theory is just a representation, not an explanation. And a representation is always abstract; you cannot account for everything. A "true" "theory of everyting" would consist of knowing simultaneously every state of everything in the world. Only then you would know the why's.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).